# Runtime error Set the secret_key error Flask

Tags: python, flask

Hi I'm trying to run my web app using `flask run` command I'm getting this issue at runtime

**RuntimeError: The session is unavailable because no secret key was set.  Set the secret_key on the application to something unique and secret.**

```
import os
from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt
from flask import Flask, render_template, request,  flash
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
import random
from flask import Flask, session
from flask_session import Session


app = Flask(__name__)
engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))


SECRET_KEY = "random key"
SESSION_PERMANENT = False
SESSION_TYPE = 'filesystem'
Session(app)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    # d = db.execute('SELECT * FROM   pg_catalog.pg_tables WHERE   schemaname != pg_catalog AND schemaname != information_schem')
    return render_template("index.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set secret key like this.

```
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'some random string'
```

Answer (score -1):

Add your secret key to config file 
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'some random string'
after add the config the same name using to _init file like ** app.config.from_object('core.config.SECRET_KEY') **. I think it is work correctly